# JQuery TypeError in CouchDB OpenDoc function

Tags: javascript, jquery, couchdb, couchapp

Though I use CouchDB-specific JQuery verison, the problem can appear to be not related to CouchDB. There is a list of document id's, and I'm using `openDoc` function from [the docs](http://daleharvey.github.com/jquery.couch.js-docs/symbols/%24.couch.db.html) to retrieve a document when user clicks the id:

```
$('.doc_name').click(function() {
    var doc_id = $(this).html().toString()
    console.log(doc_id);
    db.openDoc({
        ocId : doc_id,
        success : function(data) { console.log(data); }
    });
});
```

The rest of the code (66 lines) is [here](https://gist.github.com/1482413).

The `console.log(doc_id)` outputs a string, but I get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'split'` at the point where `docId` is processed.

What is the problem? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the docId to the first parameter of the openDoc call. Eg:

```
db.openDoc(doc_id, {
    success : function(data) { console.log(data); }
});
```

Here are some handy references for the jquery.couch.js file:

http://daleharvey.github.com/jquery.couch.js-docs/symbols/%24.couch.db.html#.openDoc

http://bradley-holt.com/2011/07/couchdb-jquery-plugin-reference/

Comment: It worked! I've seen the docs before, just haven't noticed `docId` is a separate parameter. Thank you very much!